# Call PHP from JavaScript stops grid.js from working

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to call a `PHP page` from JavaScript but don't want to use a div tag to display the results as it seems to interfere with `grid.js` which I am using. Does anybody know of a way which is easy to do. I'm not passing any valuables between the pages.

Many thanks

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "webserver", success: function(result){
      $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
});
</script>


<div id="div1"></div>
```

Comment: "seems to interfere with" isn't really an error message or problem statement we can help with. What exactly goes wrong when you run this code? What error or unexpected behaviour are you experiencing, precisely? And how is grid.js related to this? You haven't even included any code which mentions that. What is its relationship to the code above? The code you've shown above won't, on its own, cause any obvious issues.

Comment: Many thanks, for you help I think I am going to try a different method.